# How to reproduce the Selenium Error - The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am encountering the same error described in [Selenium Error - The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec).

In order to better understand the problem, I need to create a minimal sample that reproduces the bug - an html page and a console app that uses Selenium to open it.

My question is: How exactly can I reproduce the bug, i.e. create an experimental program that intentionally triggers this bug?

**Edit:** In case it helps, according to [IEDriver. Download. HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server timed out after 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377305/iedriver-download-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-server-timed-out-after):

> The problem here is that when IE is in the process of downloading a file, the readyState of the browser never moves from interactive to complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a web page which includes a button control, in the button click event, you can call a web API to get data. In the web API method, add Thread. Sleep () method to stop the executing thread for a given amount of time (more than the request time). Then, if you trigger the button click event using Selenium WebDriver, it will show this error.

Code like this:

Code in mvc view:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#buttonSearchPro").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });;
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="buttonSearchPro" class="btn btnAction" value="Download" />
```

Code in MVC controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(70000000);
        return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Code in console application:

```
    private const string URL = @"http://localhost:65330/Home/Index";
    private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"D:\Downloads\webdriver\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //EdgeWebDriver();
        InternetExplorerTest();
    }

    public static void InternetExplorerTest()
    {
        try{

        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
        {
            InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
        };
        var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
        driver.Navigate();
        //find the button and trigger click event.
        driver.FindElementById("buttonSearchPro").Click() ;
        driver.Close(); // closes browser
        driver.Quit(); // closes IEDriverServer process

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

the result like this:

[image]